# Vuejs: Date 1 is after Date 2

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to change the text color of a row if date1 is after date 2. How do we do this please. Thank you.

I tried this but it does colors everything red/danger.

```java
<tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id"
    :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': issue.datedue < new Date() }">

     <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
     <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
<tr>
```

I also tried this but it does not work

```java
<tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id"
    :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': (issue.datedue).after(new Date()) }">

     <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
     <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
<tr>
```

Edited...
Solution:
I found a way to make it work. I think the problem was the format of issue.date is different from the format of new Date()...i think.
This code worked.

```js
<tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id"
    :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': issue.datedue < new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA') }">


     <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
     <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
<tr>
```

Comment: What data type is `issue.datedue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `issue.datedue` is a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance or a timestamp in milliseconds, you can check if `issue.datedue` is **after** *now* using a *greater-than* comparison.

I would also suggest storing the current date/time in a `data` property so you're not constantly computing it.

For example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    issues: [{
      id: 1,
      firstname: 'Fred',
      lastname: 'Flintstone',
      datedue: new Date('2050-05-01T00:00:00Z') // after today
    }, {
      id: 2,
      firstname: 'Barney',
      lastname: 'Rubble',
      datedue: new Date('2020-05-01T00:00:00Z') // before today
    }],
    now: new Date() // store "now"
  }),
  updated() {
    this.now = new Date() // update if necessary
  }
})
```

```css
.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.text-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<table id="app" border="1">
  <tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id" :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': issue.datedue > now }">
    <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{ issue.datedue }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are regular js dates, then compare them by comparing the values of `getTime()` (the number of milliseconds since the epoch) on each.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    now: new Date()
  },
  methods: {
    // answer a date n days in the future (or past if n<0)
    daysFromNow(n) {
      let date = new Date(this.now.getTime())
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + n)
      return date
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span :class="{ red : daysFromNow(-1).getTime() < daysFromNow(1).getTime()  }">
    I should be red, because yesterday is less than tomorrow
  </span>
  <br/>
  <span :class="{ red : daysFromNow(-1).getTime() > daysFromNow(1).getTime()  }">
    I should be black, because yesterday is not greater than tomorrow
  </span>
</div>

<style>
  .red {
    color: red;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. The information you is very helpful.